# Paypal Error: things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later

Tags: ce-1.9.2.4, paypal-standard

We are using Magento 1.9.2.4. Suddenly we are facing issues with Paypal Standard payment method. Issue: https://prnt.sc/izpr57

Can someone help?

Comment: I believe there is a debugging option in paypal configs.  You can start here and view the paypal specific log file in <magento_root>/var/log/

Comment: thanks @camdixon we have changed paypal payment method and it is working fine now.